# Can't login with Spotify from iOS application

Tags: ios, spotify

I am currently using Spotify iOS SDK Beta 6 for my iOS application. Until yesterday night everything was working perfect. However, yesterday when I tried to login my application with Spotify but I wasn't able to even return to the application.

Basically first users opens the application and clicks to the Login with Spotify button. After that application redirects user to the safari to login with Spotify. After that user supposed to login with Facebook or Spotify account and then be return back to the application. But at this point Spotify gives an error like as follows:

[image]

First I thought it was because of rate limits and changed the application and created another application on Spotify Developer platform. But it didn't help at all. I also disconnected my Spotify account from Facebook and reconnected again.

By the way I am using a heroku application as my token exchange server. I also changed the keys over there. My Xcode version is Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a) and I am running on iOS8.1 simulator if it helps.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a glitch in handling custom protocols in the redirect URI therefore the error page. This was quickly resolved yesterday evening.

Comment: Could you provide more explanation about how this was resolved?

Comment: Yes exactly, I sent a tweet to Spotify Platform and then after couple of hours it was solved. Thanks. So the problem wasn't because of me.